# How to draw irregular inline grids/squares (related to rook polynomials)

Tags: diagrams, grids

I'm studying rook polynomials, and I want to draw some figures like the one below in LaTeX. I understand how to draw chessboards using tikz, but I can't think of a way to draw those "irregular" grids.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This can be done using the `grid` and `rectangle` paths.

```
\draw (a, b) rectangle (c, d);
```

draws a rectangle with diagonally opposite corners `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` and horizontal and vertical sides.

```
\draw (a, b) grid (c, d);
```

draws a grid within the same rectangle with the default grid spacing of 1. You can change the spacing by setting `step` so

```
\draw[step=0.5] (a, b) grid (c, d);
```

will draw grid squares half the size (so four times as many squares).

When drawing with `ultra thick` the corners of the grid don't align perfectly so I've gone over the outer boundary of the grid again with a rectangle.
You may have  to change the value of `baseline` for grids of  different size.

The first row of your image is then produced by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \left( \,
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=20pt, scale=0.5]
                \draw[ultra thick] (0, 0) grid (2, 3);
                \draw[ultra thick] (2, 1) rectangle (3, 2);
                \draw[ultra thick] (0, 0) rectangle (2, 3);
                \node at (1.5, 1.5) {\(s\)};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \, \right)
        =
        \left( \,
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=20pt, scale=0.5]
                \draw[ultra thick] (0, 0) grid (2, 3);
                \draw[ultra thick] (2, 1) rectangle (3, 2);
                \draw[ultra thick] (0, 0) rectangle (2, 3);
                \node at (1.5, 1.5) {\(X\)};
                \node at (0.5, 0.5) {\(s\)};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \, \right)
        + x
        \left( \,
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=20pt, scale=0.5]
                \draw[ultra thick] (0, 0) grid (1, 3);
                \draw[ultra thick] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 3);
                \node at (0.5, 1.5) {\(X\)};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \, \right)
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks a lot.